# Convert String31 with Comma as decimal to Float Number

Tags: julia, decimal

I have a data frame with 190 columns in the format String31? using a comma as the decimal separator. I need to replace those commas with periods and then convert them to a numeric format.

How can I do this?

I have been trying something like this:

```
function custom_parse(x::String, default::Float64)
    try
        return parse(Float64, x)
    catch
        return default
    end
end


for col in names(csv_coop_completo_1993a2022)[4:end]

    csv_coop_completo_1993a2022[!, col] = replace.(string.(csv_coop_completo_1993a2022[!, col]), "," => ".")
    
    csv_coop_completo_1993a2022[!, col] = map(x -> custom_parse(x, 0.0), csv_coop_completo_1993a2022[!, col])
end
```

But my results are shown in the format String like `2.0361331369e8`

csv

```
cnpj,ano,razao_social,10000007,11000006,11200002,39999993,60000002,61000001,61100004
171973,199312,COOPSCET,"5651,44","5651,44","5651,44","5651,44","5651,44","5651,44","8994,50"
379891,199312,CECMF CIMENTO TOCANTINS LTDA,"7429594,11","2759951,05","2759951,05","7429594,11","7161085,08","7161085,08","12550184,27"
617290,199312,"CECME SENAI-DF, LTDA","1500909,37","86432,56","86432,31","2632612,27","1573059,16","1573059,16","157922,83"
694877,199312,CECM SERV EXEC FED SECSA�DE DF,"22638658,49","306499,15","304001,15","25747440,55","24006473,31","24006473,31","20193139,66"
968602,199312,CCLA VALE S�O PATRICIO LTDA,"205124653,22","160604715,50","160469198,11","247012935,13","127063766,45","127063766,45","85617744,60"
```

Comment: What is the string that is coming out as `2.0361331369e8`?

Comment: The original value is 203613313,69

Comment: Do you use commas instead of decimals?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover in brazil we use comma as decimal mark. But here I think I need to change this to dots as decimal marks, in order to do my math. Write?

Comment: You'd get an error if Julia didn't like the comma instead of the decimal. When I run `parse(Float64, "203613313.69")` it yields `2.0361331369e8`

Comment: `parse()` is returning the float in scientific notation

Comment: As an aside, `tryparse` is better than actually using `try`...`catch`. So the function can be nicely re-rewritten as: `custom_parse(x, default) = something(tryparse(Float64, replace(x,','=>'.')),default)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I totally follow your train of thought. It seems like you want your numbers to be converted to Float64s. It also seems like you might be getting confused by the scientific notation (I am less sure about this though).

Here is how you can load the data, and then convert the relevant columns to Float64:

```
# load libraries
using WeakRefStrings, CSV, DataFrames

# read in data
data = CSV.read("/Users/myusername/Downloads/example.csv", DataFrame)

# from the fourth column to the end, replace commas with periods, and parse as Float64
[data[!,i] = parse.(Float64, replace.(data[!,i], "," => ".")) for i in 4:size(data,2)]
```

Output:

```
5×10 DataFrame
 Row │ cnpj    ano     razao_social                    10000007      11000006       11200002       39999993      60000002       ⋯
     │ Int64   Int64   String                          Float64       Float64        Float64        Float64       Float64        ⋯
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 171973  199312  COOPSCET                        5651.44        5651.44        5651.44       5651.44       5651.44        ⋯
   2 │ 379891  199312  CECMF CIMENTO TOCANTINS LTDA       7.42959e6      2.75995e6      2.75995e6     7.42959e6     7.16109e6
   3 │ 617290  199312  CECME SENAI-DF, LTDA               1.50091e6  86432.6        86432.3           2.63261e6     1.57306e6
   4 │ 694877  199312  CECM SERV EXEC FED SECSA�DE DF     2.26387e7      3.06499e5      3.04001e5     2.57474e7     2.40065e7
   5 │ 968602  199312  CCLA VALE S�O PATRICIO LTDA        2.05125e8      1.60605e8      1.60469e8     2.47013e8     1.27064e8   ⋯
                                                                                                                2 columns omitted
```